# Catching a string like #.+# with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am building a project which users should be able to generate links easily by putting: #this is the link#. And i am trying to catch strings in between 2 # symbols with regex. I have tried,

```
#.+#
```

it works perfectly if only 1 link in users string, but if there are more than 1 links like,

```
#asdfasdf asdf# asdf asfasdfasdf asd fasd fasdf #asdfasdf asdfasdf asdf asdf#
```

it catches the whole string.  But i need them separately, so i can substitute them with  tags.

Comment: a point you may want to consider: `#` is a legitimate character in URLs (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728307/catching-a-string-like-with-regex/10728349#10728349), so you might want to allow an alternate method for users who want to embed URLs that contain a `#` character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "greedy regex". By default regular expression matches the longest string possible. You can make it non-greedy this way:

```
/#.+?#/
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/7WWyaUApFt

Comment: An alternative is to explicitly say that the URL cannot contain a `#`: /#[^#]+#/`.  This will be effectively equivalent to the non-greedy match.

Answer (score 2):

Use non-greedy match

```
#.+?#
```

It will catch indivisual ones.